# python: tree = ET.parse('file.xml') use variable (getdata) in place of 'file.xml'

Tags: python, xml, parsing

this is probably a simple answer.

I can parse and convert datae from XML using whats in the title,

however I'm pulling back data from different sources and I don't want to write them all to files before parsing them as I'm going to be combining the data into one file.

So I run an api call to get some info and store it in variable (getdata)

```
    tree = ET.parse(getdata)
```

doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`fromstring`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring) method of ElementTree:

```
root_element = ET.fromstring(getdata)
```

Comment: File "03xmlTest.py", line 39, in parseXML
    root = tree.getroot()   AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getroot'

Comment: This method returns an Element instance and not an ElementTree instance. Therefore, there's no need to get the root :) Updating answer to rename variable to `root_element` for clarity.